# Java 8 differences in SOAP between update 60 and update 144

Tags: java, web-services, soap, sharepoint

I'm using Java 8 to access Sharepoint Online Web Services (SOAP), when I updated my Java version from 60 to 144, the Sharepoint Online started to response incorrectly : returns only 1/4 of the fields that was returned in Java 8u60 and Date properties were returned without Z at the end. Digging a bit deeper I found that the difference is that Java 8u60 generates SOAP with xmlns property in viewFields not empty :

```
<S:Envelope
        xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <S:Body
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <GetListItems>
                <listName>
                    {69CA20CB-91AE-4248-8998-77DE4167F3D5}
                    </listName>
                <viewName>
                    {1952971E-3E09-4797-8D6F-4E282694123A}
                    </viewName>
                <viewFields
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"
                    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
```

While Java 8u144 generates it's xmlns property in viewFields empty :

```
<S:Envelope
        xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
        <S:Body
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <GetListItems
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
                <listName>
                    {69CA20CB-91AE-4248-8998-77DE4167F3D5}
                    </listName>
                <viewName>
                    {1952971E-3E09-4797-8D6F-4E282694123A}
                    </viewName>
                <viewFields
                    xmlns=""
                    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
```

Any thoughts what can cause this strange behaviour and how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a regional setting issue. Did you uninstall and reinstall Java? Or just do an update? Did you configure it to be the same after installation.

Comment: Actually, I did install / reinstall / update, Checked different computers, and different OSs. Same behaviour, also on my colleagues computers. It's behave all the same.